# If `ModelState.IsValid==false`, we should return `View()` or `View(movie)`?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If `ModelState.IsValid==false`, we should return `View()` or `View(movie)`?

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Movies.Add(movie);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

or

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Movies.Add(movie);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(movie);
        }
    }
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if you want to clear the form or not.

Returning the Model will place the values the user entered back into the form where returning view() will display an empty form on post back.

Comment: Why post back? "returning view() will display an empty form or post back."

Comment: This is wrong, the posted values are kept in `ModelState`, you don't need a model to keep the state of the form. And not passing the model does not clear the form, you have to clear the `ModelState`.

Comment: Interesting that could explain some things.

Answer (score 1):

Always return the same model when validation fails (return View(movie); )

Comment: I don't agree with this and I do agree with Michael - this is dependent on business logic - there is no right or wrong way.

Comment: If you don't want to return a field (say it's a password or captcha textbox), you set model.password = null ect.. You don't need the overhead of creating a new instance of the model.

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
{
   this.ViewData.Model = movie;
...
```

That way I can return `View()` without worrying about passing the model as argument. There can be more than one situation where you may want to return the view, e.g. try/catch around SaveChanges(). This also gives you the chance to handle errors on the `OnException` method and return a view without losing the model.